# How to make the column with line scatter graph. (Double Y)

Tags: diagrams, plot, bar-chart

I want to make this graph. I have only excel data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the data as text into the question?

Comment: Please provide some code of what you already have. Read the manual of `pgfplots` to get started. We will be happy to help you, if you ask specific question on single issues. Like this, it is a "do it for me" post and it leaves all the coding (and typing) to the volunteers here.